# Onpremise Databases to Azure SQL Databases and Sync continuously

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-sync

My requirements are as below :

1. Move 3 SAP local databases to 3 Azure SQL DB.
2. Then Sync daily transactions or data to azure every night. If transactions of local DB are already exists in azure, update process will do on these transactions if not insert process will do.
3. Local systems will not stop after moving to azure. They will still goes about 6 months.

Note :

1. **We are not compatible with Azure Data Sync process because of it's
       limitations - only support 500 tables, can't sync no primary keys
       table, no views and no procedure. It also increase database size on
       both(local and azure).**
2. **Azure Data Factory Pipeline can fulfill my requirements but I have
   to create pipeline and procedure manually for each table. (SAP has
   over 2000 tables, not good for me)**
3. **We don't use azure VM and Manage Instance**

Can you guide me the best solution to move and sync? I am new to azure.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that ADF basically meets your needs, I will try to start from ADF. Actually,you don't need to manually create each table one by one.The creation could be done in the ADF sdk or powershell script or REST api. Please refer to the official document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/

So,if you could get the list of SAP table names(i found this thread:https://answers.sap.com/questions/7375575/how-to-get-all-the-table-names.html) ,you could loop the list and execute the codes to create pipelines in the batch.Only [table name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sap-table#dataset-properties) property need to be set.